# XsltListViewWebPart - run some javascript after async refresh

Tags: web-part, jquery, data-view-web-part

I've got an xslstlistviewwebpart, and set in the AJAX options to refresh the webpart every 15 sec. Is there a way to hook up some javascript code after the webpart is refreshed?

Larsi

Comment: Did you get around this issue? If yes can you let me know the solution. I want to run some javascript after async refresh of XsltListViewWebPart. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok, I figured this out, and posted an answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4861190/jquery-hook-into-a-ajax-response

Larsi